# can two users share the same Request.UserHostAddress

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, network-programming, request

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application, which is available to public users (no login is required) . and i need to prevent the same user from submitting more than 5 contact us requests within an hour. so i need a way to differentiate if the Request i am receiving  is coming from the same user or not. so i found the  `Request.UserHostAddress` , which will contain the user IP (if i am not wrong the public IP). but my question is will this value be unique per user all over the world ? or users might share this value ? if the answer is that  users might share the  `Request.UserHostAddress` , so which value will give me better way to "authenticate" the user ??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross post of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101108/can-two-users-share-the-same-request-userhostaddress

Answer (score 2):

> will this value be unique per user all over the world ?

No. It will be unique to the point where the user connects to the internet. All users behind a specific router/firewall will use the same IP address.

> which value will give me better way to "authenticate" the user

There is no such value. How it's usually handled is by setting a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple users on the same NAT-based router will have the same public IP address. Take a look at this artice on security stackexchange for alternatives:
    https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81302/how-to-uniquely-identify-users-with-the-same-external-ip-address